# Properties Characterising the Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The normal distribution with mean $0$ has some remarkable properties. The sum of two independent normal distributions $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)+\mathcal{N}(0,\tau)$ is still a normal distribution, just a scaled version of either one. By the CLT, this property is unique among distributions with variance. Are there examples of distributions without variance where this holds?

Comment: Any stable distribution has the property that If $(X_i)$ is i.i.d with  this distribution  then $a_n( X_1+x_1+..+X_n)+b_n$ has the same distribution for some $a_n$ and $b_n$. Any stable r.v. other than  a normal one has infinite variance.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) says "... the normal distribution, the Cauchy distribution, and the Lévy distribution ... are special cases of stable distributions."